# Passing data from php to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-maps

I'm creating a Google Maps application. I need to load location data from a database with Ajax, so I can show these data every x seconds. I'm using CodeIgniter/PHP. This is what I got:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
             <title>Simple Map</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            html, body {
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            #map {
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map"></div>
        <script>
            var map;
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                    zoom: 8
                });


                httpCall();
            }

            function httpCall($http) {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: '<?php echo site_url('User/marks') ?>',
                    data: data,
                    dataType: "json"
                })
                        .success(function (markers) {
                            for (var i = 0, len = markers.length; i < len; ++i) {
                                var myLatLng = {lat: markers[i].lat, lng: markers[i].lng};

                                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position: {
                                        lat: parseFloat(markers[i].lat),
                                        lng: parseFloat(markers[i].lng)
                                    },
                                    map: map
                                });
                            }
                        })
            }

        </script>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

the User/marks function is:

```
function marks() {
    echo json_encode($this->user_model->get_marks());
}
```

user_model get marks function is:

```
        function get_marks() {
            $sql = "select lat,lng 
from tbl_locations";
            $query = $this->db->query($sql);
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
        }
```

My error is:

```
ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

Apparently I pass the data incorrectly, but what is the correct way?

Comment: Your callback function takes data but you reference markers. Change your success from function(data) to function(markers)

Comment: You have a lot of errors in your code.  Variables (data, markers, $http) don't line up.  It looks like code might have been copied from multiple places.  Please do more research on the technologies you are trying to use before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Your success callback function takes `data` but you reference `markers`.

Change your `.success(function(...){})` from `function(data)` to `function(markers)`.

You also have an undefined reference to `data` in your $http construction.  I don't know where this is coming from though.

**Edit: **

```
function httpCall($http) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '<?php echo site_url('User/marks') ?>',
                data: data, //This is the issue right here
                dataType: "
```

In this structure, the `data` before the ':' is a property. The `data`after the ':' is a variable.  The `data` variable is *never* declared.  For more maintainable/readable code, you should actually rename the `data` variable so this is clear.

For example,

```
var dataToSendToServer = { } //declare an empty object
```

Then update your httpCall method:

```
function httpCall($http) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '<?php echo site_url('User/marks') ?>',
                data: dataToSendToServer,
                dataType: "json"
            })
```

Comment: I edited my code and the original post. But I still get the same error. "data is not defined"

Comment: You're also referencing an undefined `data` in your $http above dataType.  `data: *data*`.

Comment: Sorry, replace "data: data," to "data: *data*"? Thx for your help